# DateTime matches between Timespan/Timezone

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I need to check if a DateTime variable matches between two week times.

Something like **23.11.2016 14:08** is or was **between**:

- **Monday 18:00 and Monday 22:00** 
  or
- **Monday 22:00 and Tuesday 07:00**

At the moment i can check if the Day is between the correct days:

```
DateTime dTime = DateTime.Parse(/*String from sql database*/);
                                  // German weekday abbreviations
String[] Days = new string[] { "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa", "So" };

string Day = dTime.ToString("ddd", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
string DayFrom = "Di";
string DayTill = "Mi";

int DayposStop = Array.IndexOf(Days, Day);
int DayposFrom = Array.IndexOf(Days, DayFrom);
int DayposTill = Array.IndexOf(Days, DayTill);

if (((DayposFrom <= Daypos || Daypos <= DayposTill)
```

I started to build something which looks nearly the same for the time but
that didn't worked.

Is there an easier way i don't know of or another solution?
I just need to check if someone worked outside of the regular working period.

Comment: `('23.11.2016 18.00' < '23.11.2016 14:08' <= '23.11.2016 22.00') || ('23.11.2016 22.00' < '23.11.2016 14:08' <= '24.11.2016 07.00').` This is what you need, right?

Comment: yeah something like that but i do not have dates its just Monday or Friday no 21.Oktober or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying and searching a lot i came to the conclusion that i couldn´t solve my problen in the specific way i want (with time periods between working shifts and holidays etc.) but i found a 3rd party libary which can provide everything i could possibly need.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Answer (score 1):

I edit all to change the answer since, I did not understand your question very well.

You can do the following:

```
TimeSpan timeFrom = new TimeSpan(15,40,00);
TimeSpan timeUntil = new TimeSpan(22,00,00);

if (yourDate.TimeOfDay > timeFrom && yourDate.TimeOfDay < timeUntil)
{
    return;
}
```

For checking the day of the week you can take what Sefe answered before.

Comment: won´t work for me because the dates to check aren´t really dates its just Monday 12:00 to Monday 13:00 every week so not a real date.

Comment: Edited, to change my answer to fit your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.DayOfWeek`:

```
DateTime dTime = DateTime.Parse(/*String from sql database*/);
DayOfWeek weekdayFrom = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
DayOfWeek weekdayTo = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;

if ((dTime.DayOfWeek >= weekdayFrom) && (dTime.DayOfWeek <= weekdayTo))
```

One sidenote though: the DayOfWeek enumeration starts on Sunday as the first day and ends with Saturday as the last day. If that matters to you, you have to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek` to offset your weekday first.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to check your time, too you will have to check the actual time difference:

```
DateTime dTime = DateTime.Parse(/*String from sql database*/);
DayOfWeek weekdayFrom = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
DayOfWeek weekdayTo = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
double hourFrom = 12;
double hourTo = 18;

DateTime periodStart = dTime.AddDays(weekdayFrom - dTime.DayOfWeek).Date.AddHours(hourFrom);
DateTime periodEnd = dTime.AddDays(weekdayTo - dTime.DayOfWeek).Date.AddHours(hourTo);

if ((dTime >= periodStart) && (dTime <= periodEnd))
```

Again, you might need to offset with `FirstDayOfWeek`.

Comment: that would shorten my code above great but what with the Timespan between like 10:00 and 16:00 ?